# How to divide all objects into parts

Tags: django, django-templates

I have for section in my template:

```
{% for image in gallery.images.all %}
    <div id="image{{ image.id }}" class="frame">
        <img src="{{ image.url_125x125 }}" alt="{{ image.name }}" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to divide this forloop section into parts, each with 5 elements for example, like this:

```
{% for image in gallery.images.all|slice:"5:" %}
    <div id="image{{ image.id }}" class="frame">
        <img src="{{ image.url_125x125 }}" alt="{{ image.name }}" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% for image in gallery.images.all|slice:"5:5" %}
    <div id="image{{ image.id }}" class="frame">
        <img src="{{ image.url_125x125 }}" alt="{{ image.name }}" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% for image in gallery.images.all|slice:"10:5" %}
    <div id="image{{ image.id }}" class="frame">
        <img src="{{ image.url_125x125 }}" alt="{{ image.name }}" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}

etc...
```

But I don't now how many images are in gallery. How to do it automatic? I know it's something of forloop.counter but I do not know how :) forloop.counter modulo 5 ?

Comment: What it the purpose of such division? Pagination? Then you can try [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator) from django. You can't do modulo arithmetic operation in django templates.

Comment: no i want to show only 5 images at same time and using jquery to showing next

Comment: May be you should think about writing custom tag then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you just split it apart in your view? populate a list with lists of 5 elements until you run out? Then in your template you just iterate through each one of those 5 section chunks???

Comment: Yes, I think of that way but I wanted to avoid that.